# Using Web Applications as a product support forum

Tags: discussion, tags, scope, asking-questions

I'm looking into using webapps.stackexchange.com as a support forum for our product [Orangedox for Dropbox](https://dropbox.orangedox.com). Since I'm a big fan of Stack Overflow I would rather use a product like this, where anyone can answer the question, instead of the usual product specific forum.

The idea is to simply provide two links for the user

- One to browse [previously answered questions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orangedox)
- and one to [ask a question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=orangedox)

However, I'm a little concerned with a couple of points

1. This will require the user to sign-up for Web Apps, or at the minimum re-enter their name and email
2. You need 300+ reputation to create a new tag "orangedox"

Does anyone have experience using Web Apps as the main help forum for their site?

**Bonus**! if you have 300+ reputation on Web Apps and you don't mind asking a question about Orangedox for Dropbox so the tag "orangedox" can be created that would be a huge help

**UPDATE**
Following [Eight Days of Malaise](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/410/eight-days-of-malaise) answer below here is what we've come up with for a solution. Comments are encouraged

[image: Support Page]

Comment: Maybe have the bug report above the link to Web Apps, since it's common to see some users think they should report bugs on any of the SE sites

Comment: sure thing .. thanks again!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Posting on Web Applications does not require signing up.

New users can just come in and post their questions.

However, they can't create the orangedox [tag unless they also have 300 reputation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags). But, higher reputation users will shortly come along and add the tag if it fits.

Keep in mind that you [can't funnel all your support](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/957/trello-is-making-its-users-think-were-a-bug-tracker-or-place-for-feature-reques) to Web Applications, as it has [to be supplemental](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/960/how-do-i-launch-my-new-free-service-leveraging-webapps-without-running-afoul-of) to the main support you already [take care of on your side](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project/13282#13282).

If you do post, [be sure to mark your affiliation with the product](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1028/what-is-the-official-policy-on-identifying-yourself-as-a-team-member-for-a-produ).

Comment: Thanks for the linked resources, I'm going to follow the guide lines mentioned by 
Jon Skeet in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project  .. also I'll be sure to post up the link here that describes how we point to Web Apps

Answer (score 9):

As long as the questions asked here are on-topic for Web Apps, they'll be welcome, although I expect that they'll require some very specific knowledge that may not be well-represented here. If you're planning on answering the questions then that's all to the good.

I would caution you, however, against attempting to turn Web Apps into your general-support forum. There are a lot of questions that your users might have that *will not* be welcome here: Bug reports. Feature requests. (Actually, Eight Days of Malaise links to several good resources in [his answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2664/354).) When those ill-fitting questions are ultimately closed and deleted here, your users will look at you in a negative light.

Further, we don't create tags ahead of time. (The software doesn't support it, actually). Once there is an actual question then we can create a tag.